# Windows 7 from Dreamspark

Tags: windows-7, dreamspark

In my university I get key from Windows 7. As I know it is from Dreamspark. But I got no Windows 7 image. I mean, I can get it in university but I tought that maybe I can download it by myself?

I know that it's for the proffesional version.

I found this version. Would it fit?

`7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_client_ru-ru_Retail_Professional-GRMCPRXFRER_RU_DVD.iso`

**UPD**
Is anybody here who used Dreamspark Windows?

Comment: As long as your key is for the Professional then that image would indeed work assuming its actually legitimate

Comment: @Ramhound it's original MSDN image as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might or might not. It depends on what kind of key you have. Is it an OEM key, Volume licenced key, etc...

You need to have the right version to make it work. They likely use a volume licenced version, and this is not that, so it probably is not going to work, but again, that is purely speculation.

At this point, either ask at your university, or just try and install it and see if it accepts the key. If you don't want to ruin your install until you are sure, use a Virtual Machine such as Oracle Virtual Box.

Comment: well, i found two versions
this
`7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_professional_ru-ru_VL_UPG_OEM_Professional-GRMCPRXVCCP_RU_DVD.iso`

Comment: and that 
`7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_professional_ru-ru_VL_OEM_Professional-GRMCPRXVOL_RU_DVD.iso`

Comment: which one do you think would fit?

Comment: As I said before, its all speculation. I'm affraid you either have to ask the university for the specific version or try them all.

Comment: I asked and they give me that name `ru_windows_7_professional_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_677024`

Comment: So there you go. :) Doesn't seem to be a volume licence key.

Comment: well, I checked sha-1 checksums of iso files which I dowloaded with it this `6AAFBBFFC12BB63894932210D5BCB69773B46C98` and nothing compared :\